# Optional chaining (?.) in nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, nashorn

I use nashorn in my project. I want get property from a json, but property may not have value.

In javascript, use optional chaining and set a value, if property is null; but in nashorn, when I use (?.), I get this error:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
import javax.script.Bindings

@Service
class SampleService {

    class Person(
            val firstName: String,
            val lastName: String,
            val child: Child?
    )

    class Child(
            val name: String,
            val age: Int
    )

    fun runScript() {
        val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn")
        val bindings: Bindings = engine.createBindings()
        val person = Person("John", "Smite", null)
        bindings["person"] = person
        try {
            val script = """
               var childAge = person.child?.age ?? 0;
               childAge; //return as result.
            """.trimIndent()
            val scriptResult: Any = engine.eval(script, bindings)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }

    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:28 Expected an operand but found .
var childAge = person.child?.age ?? 0;
^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 28
```

I checked this link, but I could not solve the problem:
[Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't think `?:` is valid JS syntax.

Comment: `json?.id ?: 'value if null'` is not valid JavaScript syntax; you should be getting a syntax error, not a runtime error. Did you mean `json?.id ?? 'value if null'`? (E.g., combining optional chaining with nullish coalescing.) Separately, if you're writing modern JavaScript (as you appear to be), don't use `var`, use `let` or `const`.

Comment: Is this javascript or java.  `?:` is an available operator in java languages such as groovy.

Comment: You can mix languages in nashorn? Is the code in this question Java or JavaScript?

Comment: The Nashorn Javascript Engine is part of Java SE 8 and competes with other standalone engines like Google V8. I add java service and use functions in script.
I guess can use java syntax in this library.
@evolutionxbox

Comment: I test it, but get this error again.@T.J.Crowder

Comment: Why does that mean Java syntax can be used in JavaScript? V8 is written in C, but that doesn't mean we use C syntax in JavaScript. --- Is the code you've provided JavaScript that is executed by Nashorn?

Comment: Yes, the code is javascript and executed by nashorn.@evolutionxbox

Comment: Well, do you know that Nashorn supports optional chaining? It's fairly new. (But if it doesn't, again, I'd expect a syntax error, not an error about using a property of `null`.) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem: A Java class (complete with `import`s) that tries to run your JavaScript code via Nashorn, that someone can copy and paste into a file on their machine to replicate exactly the error you're quoting in the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - No, Nashorn doesn't allow you to mix Java and JavaScript syntax in the same expression. :-) It lets you execute JavaScript code within a Java program, but it...has to be JavaScript code. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification! 

Comment: I Edit the question and add a example.@T.J.Crowder

Comment: I found optional chaining is pretty new and old browser not supported this feature. I guess the version of nashorn is not supported. How can increase the version of nashorn's javascript?@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the OP would like to ask you a question, but they didn't tag you correctly.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox. mgh - I don't know a lot about Nashorn, but I note from [the WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) that it claims to support "ECMAScript 5.1" (so: really out of date), and that it's deprecated in JDK 11 and will be removed from JDK 15 onward. So there probably isn't any version of Nashorn that supports optional chaining (or anything else vaguely recent). You can use the ES5-level code `var childAge = person.child && person.child.age || 0;`, or upgrade and use the Nashorn replacement [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current strategy for Nashorn is to follow the ECMAScript specification. When we release with JDK 8 we will be aligned with ECMAScript 5.1.[link](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/)

The the Nashorn engine has been deprecated in JDK 11 as part of JEP 335 and is scheduled to be removed from future JDK releases as part of JEP 372.

> **GraalVM JavaScript** can step in as a replacement for code previously executed on the Nashorn engine. It provides all the
> features previously provided by Nashorn, with many being available by
> default, some behind flags, some requiring minor modifications to your
> source code.[link](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NashornMigrationGuide.md)

Optional chaining is pretty new and ECMAScript 5.1 is not supported this feature.

I migrate from **nashorn** to **GraalVM JavaScript** and changed the code as follows:

```
import com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context
import org.graalvm.polyglot.HostAccess
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import javax.script.ScriptEngine


@Service
class SampleService {

    data class Person(
            val firstName: String,
            val lastName: String,
            val child: Child?
    )

    data class Child(
            val name: String,
            val age: Int
    )

    fun runScript() {

        val person = Person("John", "Smite", null)

        val engine: ScriptEngine = GraalJSScriptEngine.create(null,
                Context.newBuilder("js")
                        .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                        .allowExperimentalOptions(true)
                        .option("js.ecmascript-version", "2020")
                        .option("js.nashorn-compat", "true"))
        engine.put("person", person)
        try {
            val script = """
                print(person.child?.name);
                //print undefined
                print(person.child?.name ?? 'not exist');
                //print not exist
            """.trimIndent()
            engine.eval(script)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note you don't need to set `.option("js.ecmascript-version", "2020")`, this is the current default anyway (you only need to set it if you want to fix this version, and not automatically update to newer versions in the future.

For `.option("js.nashorn-compat", "true")` you should only set that if you REALLY need that. Better check if your code runs without the nashorn-compat mode (from what I see here, it should!) - the compat mode kind of locks you in to that specific environment; you might have to change a thing or two, but that avoids complications in the future.

Comment: If I remove nashorn, how binding data to script? I want binding `Person` and use in script.@ChristianWirth